# how to use sizeof with a variable of a derived class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, sizeof

I am trying to get the size of a derived class, but I can't...

```
class one_t {
    size_t getsizeof() { return sizeof(*this); }     
    ... other members ... 
};

class two_t : public one_t {
    ... supplemental members ...
};
    
void main()
{
    two_t _2;
    
    ::cout << _2.getsizeof(); 
}
```

The output is always 8!

Comment: Make "getsizeof" virtual ? Just use sizeof(_2) ?

Comment: Why not just use `sizeof(_2)` instead of trying to invent `_2.getsizeof()`?

Comment: @John3136 making it virtual would require every derived class reimplement it. Might be the simplest solution though.

Comment: Might also be possible to solve with CRTP but that's more trouble than it's worth. Gives me a headache just thinking about it.

Comment: I badly need to have the size of a derived class from a base class according to a non null pointer and it would be so great without a virtual function

Comment: @blueperfect "*I badly need to have the size of a derived class from a base class according to a non null pointer and it would be so great without a virtual function*" - why? What exactly are you actually trying to accomplish? Please [edit] your post to provide more details. If all you have is a pointer to a base class, then a `virtual` method is the only way, without `dynamic_cast`'ing the pointer to every possible derived class.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't work the way you are attempting.

Even though you are calling `getsizeof()` on a `two_t` object, the *implicit* `this` pointer that is inside of `one_t::getsizeof()` is a `one_t*` pointer, which you are dereferencing, so you end up passing a `one_t&` reference to `sizeof()`. It doesn't know `this` is really pointing at a `two_t` object, it can only return the size of whatever you actually give it, which in this case is the size of `one_t`.

To accomplish what you want, you can make `getsizeof()` be `virtual` in `one_t` and `override` it in `two_t`, eg:

```cpp
class one_t {
public:
    virtual size_t getsizeof() const { return sizeof(*this); }
    ... other members ... 
};

class two_t : public one_t {
public:
    size_t getsizeof() const override { return sizeof(*this); }
    ... supplemental members ...
};
    
void main()
{
    one_t _1;
    std::cout << _1.getsizeof(); // returns sizeof(one_t)

    two_t _2;
    std::cout << _2.getsizeof(); // returns sizeof(two_t)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) (provided you never make instances of `one_t` directly), eg:

```cpp
template<typename Derived>
class one_t {
public:
    size_t getsizeof() const { return sizeof(Derived); }
    ... other members ... 
};

class two_t : public one_t<two_t> {
public:
    ... supplemental members ...
};
    
void main()
{
    // one_t<> _2; // illegal
    // std::cout << _2.getsizeof(); 

    two_t _2;    
    std::cout << _2.getsizeof(); // returns sizeof(two_t)
}
```

Alternatively, in C++23 and later, you can use [Deducing this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) instead of CRTP, eg:

```cpp
class one_t {
public:
    template<class Self>
    size_t getsizeof(this const Self& self) const { return sizeof(self); }
    ... other members ... 
};

class two_t : public one_t {
public:
    ... supplemental members ...
};
    
void main()
{
    one_t _1;
    std::cout << _1.getsizeof(); // Self is deduced as one_t

    two_t _2;
    std::cout << _2.getsizeof(); // Self is deduced as two_t
}
```

Comment: Pretty solution.....but I cannit use it...

Comment: @blueperfect Which part? These are pretty much your only options available. You need to provide more detail about what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C++ Standard the function main shall have the return type `int`

```
int main()
```

You need to declare the function as virtual. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    class one_t 
    {
    public:
        virtual ~one_t() = default;
        virtual size_t getsizeof() const { return sizeof( *this ); }
        int x;
    };

    class two_t : public one_t 
    {
    public:
        size_t getsizeof() const override { return sizeof( *this ); }

        int y;
    };

    std::cout << one_t().getsizeof() << '\n';
    std::cout << two_t().getsizeof() << '\n';
}
```

The program output might look like

```
8
12
```

Comment: Thats not what I need... I really need the size of the derived instance within the base class

Comment: But sure the result is the correct result

Comment: @blueperfect "*I really need the size of the derived instance within the base class*" - why? What are you actually trying to do with that information? The options that have been presented to you are pretty much the only ways to accomplish this. Why do none of these options suit your need? Be specific.

Comment: In the call of a virtual function for debugging purposes I always call up the derived function... In every overtiden function I display the class name (that is "one_t") so that every object can describe every part of itself... But I want to include the size of the considered part... Computed as sum of all members of each derived class...the sum of all subsizes should be the size of all members of the whole instance)... Then i would use it for debugging purposes

Comment: That is where i cant understand why sizeof doesnt suit